# 3D graph using Google Charts API

Tags: php, charts, visualization, data-visualization

I am currently creating a graph using Google Chart API. I have a data-set which contains a months worth of data.

For example:

```
{
    '1':{
        'date':'01-01-2012',
        'dow':'01', // Monday
        'profit':'326', // GBP
    }, '2':{
        'date':'02-01-2012',
        'dow':'02', // Tuesday
        'profit':'142'
    } 
}
```

This is just a bit that I made up, but imagine this for 3 months worth of data, and I need to create a comparison graph of all Mondays (and Tuesdays, Wednesdays, etc), to show any profit patterns/anomalies which may have occured.

The problems I have is that

1. I don't think Google Charts API can invoke a Z-Axis which would be useful.
2. I can't figure out how I would group all Days of Week and dates successfully (in order).

So I guess why question would be, "How would I do this?".

Here is a screenshot of what I have got already:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2LXxN.png]

Obviously, that's just the dates in order, I need to compare the days-of-week yet.

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: any special reason why you are using google for this?

Comment: Nope, just the main free charting API that I know. Flot didn't do the job either. The only thing is, I want it to be a Javascript API

Comment: Why not simply have a weekly summary for the whole week, instead of daily points? If you care about comparing Mondays and Tuesdays... have a different chart for each DOW with a relevant filter. You can have 5 or 7 such graphs, side by side.